error with config gcc for setting up atheros csi tool openwrt
I am currently trying to setup openwrt on ubuntu virtual box but there is an error with config the file the gcc, verison is the latest and its installed when i run make menuconfig command this is the result;



fatal: Invalid revision range ee53a240ac902dc83209008a2671e7fdcf55957a..HEAD

fatal: Invalid revision range ee53a240ac902dc83209008a2671e7fdcf55957a..a7830185a86b8409bea57053222b738563abb6c9

Checking 'working-make'... ok.

Checking 'case-sensitive-fs'... ok.

Checking 'proper-umask'... ok.

Checking 'gcc'... failed.

Checking 'working-gcc'... failed.

Checking 'g++'... failed.

Checking 'working-g++'... failed.

Checking 'ncurses'... ok.

Checking 'perl-thread-queue'... ok.

Checking 'tar'... ok.

Checking 'find'... ok.

Checking 'bash'... ok.

Checking 'patch'... ok.

Checking 'diff'... ok.

Checking 'cp'... ok.

Checking 'seq'... ok.

Checking 'awk'... ok.

Checking 'grep'... ok.

Checking 'getopt'... ok.

Checking 'stat'... ok.

Checking 'unzip'... ok.

Checking 'bzip2'... ok.

Checking 'wget'... ok.

Checking 'time'... ok.

Checking 'perl'... ok.

Checking 'python'... ok.

Checking 'git'... ok.

Checking 'file'... ok.

Checking 'ldconfig-stub'... ok.



Build dependency: Please install the GNU C Compiler (gcc) 4.8 or later cc -dumpversion | grep -E '^(4\.[8-9]|[5-9]\.?)'

Build dependency: 

Please reinstall the GNU C Compiler (4.8 or later) - it appears to be broken

Build dependency: Please install the GNU C++ Compiler (g++) 4.8 or later g++ -dumpversion | grep -E '^(4\.[8-9]|[5-9]\.?)'






any idea on how to solve it
I tried to install some of the older versions or reinstalling but it didn't work.
